# Update to tables at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, django

Please blow are my code and a screenshot of my error. What I'm not doing right.[image: error message]

```
def UpdateStock(request, pk):
stock = Stock.objects.get(id=pk)
stock_form = StockForm(instance = stock)
history_form = StockHistoryForm(instance = Stock)
if request.method == 'POST':
    stock_form = StockForm(request.POST, instance = stock)
    history_form = StockHistoryForm(request.POST, instance = Stock)
    if stock_form.is_valid() and history_form.is_valid():
        stock = stock_form.save()
        history = history_form.save()
        return redirect('inventory')

context = {
    'stock_form': stock_form,
    'history_form': history_form
}

return render(request, 'inventory/edit.html', context)
```

Comment: `instance=stock`, not `Stock`, since `Stock` is a class, not an object.

Comment: Willem, please I realized that mistake and corrected it but it still throws the error Stock.category" must be a "Category" instance